# Go type switch with `time.Time`

Tags: unit-testing, go, reflection

In my test I have a function that can get a value from a struct like this:

```
func getField(v interface{}, field string) string {
    r := reflect.ValueOf(v)
    f := reflect.Indirect(r).FieldByName(field)
    t := f.Kind()

    switch t {
    case reflect.Int, reflect.Int64:
        return strconv.FormatInt(f.Int(), 10)
    case reflect.String:
        return f.String()
    case reflect.Bool:
        if f.Bool() {
            return "true"
        }
        return "false"
    return ""
}
```

This works for the types above but I can't get it to work for `time.Time`. How do I do this?

Comment: `time.Time` is a struct, so `reflect.Struct` if you're looking for the kind, or else do `f.Interface()` to get the field value as an `interface{}` and then do type assertion on it `if t, ok := f.Interface().(time.Time); ok { ...`.

Comment: ... example of the above comment https://play.golang.org/p/T9yG5PoRbP

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Judging from what you are trying to do, you don't really need reflection after getting the field. Here is a sample that works with `time.Time` too.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
    "strconv"
    "time"
)

func getField(v interface{}, field string) string {
    r := reflect.ValueOf(v)
    f := reflect.Indirect(r).FieldByName(field)
    fieldValue := f.Interface()

    switch v := fieldValue.(type) {
    case int64:
        return strconv.FormatInt(v, 10)
    case int32:
        return strconv.FormatInt(int64(v), 10)
    case int:
        return strconv.FormatInt(int64(v), 10)
    case string:
        return v
    case bool:
        if v {
            return "true"
        }
        return "false"
    case time.Time:
        return v.String()
    default:
        return ""
    }
}

type MyStruct struct {
    Name   string
    Number int32
    Is     bool
    Clock  time.Time
}

func main() {
    s := MyStruct{}
    fmt.Println(getField(s, "Name"))
    fmt.Println(getField(s, "Number"))
    fmt.Println(getField(s, "Is"))
    fmt.Println(getField(s, "Clock"))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It took me two hours to finally fix this problem. In fact, the underlying implementation of the time type is a struct, You can find out if you check its kind

```
const TimeStringKind = "time.Time"

func getFieldName(obj interface{}, columnName string) reflect.Value {
    defer func() {
        if err := recover(); err != nil {
            Log.Errorf("parse cloumn error : %s", err)
        }
    }()

    t := reflect.ValueOf(obj)

    if t.Kind() == reflect.Ptr {
        t = t.Elem()
    }

    ...
        // what made me wrong
        if t.Kind() != reflect.Struct && t.Kind() != reflect.Slice {
            return t
        }
    }

    // fix patch code
    if t.Type().String() == TimeStringKind {
        return t
    }

    return reflect.Value{}
}

func GetFieldNameString(obj interface{}, columnName string) string {
    value := getFieldName(obj, columnName)

    if !reflect.DeepEqual(value, reflect.Value{}) {
        switch value.Type().String() {
        case "string", "int":
            return value.String()
        case TimeStringKind:
            return value.Interface().(time.Time).String()
        }
    }
    return ""
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function which tests whether a `reflect.Value` represents a `time.Time` object:

```
func isTime(obj reflect.Value) bool {
    _, ok := obj.Interface().(time.Time)
    return ok
}
```

(full code on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/GCTGuV6XGc4)).

Answer (score -1):

Just for having an alternative solution, you can always hold *kind*s as *var*s and use them in a case.

```
var timeKind = reflect.TypeOf(time.Time{}).Kind()

func getField(v interface{}, field string) string {
    r := reflect.ValueOf(v)
    f := reflect.Indirect(r).FieldByName(field)
    t := f.Kind()

    switch t {
    case reflect.Int, reflect.Int64:
        return strconv.FormatInt(f.Int(), 10)
    case reflect.String:
        return f.String()
    case reflect.Bool:
        if f.Bool() {
            return "true"
        }
        return "false"
    case timeKind: // i am here!!!
       // do whatever you want
    return ""
}
```

Comment: This will actually return true for _any_ struct.